# Why is it not possible to remove elements from a std::map using reverse iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, associative-array, std

I was looking for the most efficient and expressive way to remove the last element from a `std::map`. I tried:

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(1,1));
    m.erase(m.crbegin());
    return 0;
}
```

The code does not compile, since `std::map::erase` can take [only](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) `std::map::const_iterator`.

Moreover, prior to C++11 it could take `std::map::iterator`s  as well, but for some reason, this functionality was removed too.

What is the motivation behind these restrictions?

Comment: Does const_iterator define a conversion constructor from an iterator?

Comment: @jschultz410, oh yes, that could be the reason for the deprecation in C++11.

Comment: If so, I'm just speculating here, then these functions would be more general and wouldn't violate the const'ness of the const_iterators because you aren't altering the value itself but rather removing it from the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`erase()` now take `const_iterator`s to make `const_iterator` actually useful. `iterator` is convertible to `const_iterator`, so the original functionality is not affected.

`reverse_iterator` is an iterator adapter; it exposes a `.base()` member function to get the underlying iterator, which you can pass to the container member functions. That said, `crbegin().base()` is `end()`, and passing `end()` to `erase()` is UB.

Comment: Thank you! So I have to do `m.erase(--m.end())`?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik I'd go with `m.erase(std::prev(m.end()))`. `--` isn't guaranteed to work on rvalues.